# Why does this function alert the URL but none of it's string segments?

Tags: javascript, debugging

Why does this code alert the url but neither of the other two alerts after I split/slice the string.  As far as I know, either of these methods should split the url as I would but neither are working for some reason.

```
window.onload = function getPhpExt() {
    var url = window.location;
    alert(url);

    var getinfo = url.split("?");
    alert(getinfo[1]);

    var n=url.indexOf("?");
    var getinfo2 = url.slice(n);
    alert(getinfo2);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location) is an object and not a string so split is returning an error.

You could use `window.location.href` instead

Answer (score 1):

Just use `window.location.search` directly.

```
alert( window.location.search.substr(1) );
```

BTW you don't have to wait for `onload`.

Comment: @CrashLanding - You don't need any handler. Just run your code whenever you want.